# RGB to HSV conversion results in noisy image

Tags: c#, image, rgb, hsv

My application is working for color segmentation but it's not working properly. The image on the right bottom is the HSV one but it's VERY noisy and strange and I have no idea why.

[image]

This is my code:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> frame_drone = null; //Original do drone
Image<Hsv, Byte> frame_drone_hsv = new Image<Hsv, Byte>(1280, 720); //processado drone hsv
Image<Gray,Byte> frame_drone_processado = new Image<Gray, Byte>(1280, 720); //processado drone
Image<Gray, Byte> frame_drone_canny = new Image<Gray, Byte>(1280, 720); //canny drone       

int erosao = 3;
int dilatacao = 9;             
StructuringElementEx elemento_erosao = new StructuringElementEx(erosao, erosao, 1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_ELEMENT_SHAPE.CV_SHAPE_RECT); //elemento kernelx,kernely,anchorx,anchory
StructuringElementEx elemento_dilatacao = new StructuringElementEx(dilatacao, dilatacao, 1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_ELEMENT_SHAPE.CV_SHAPE_RECT); //elemento kernelx,kernely,anchorx,anchory            

frame_drone.SmoothMedian(3); //Filtro mediana antes da passagem para HSV
frame_drone_hsv = frame_drone.Convert<Hsv, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp(); //Converte a imagem da camera RGB para HSV             
frame_drone_processado = frame_drone_hsv.InRange(new Hsv(hl.Value, sl.Value, vl.Value), new Hsv(hh.Value, sh.Value, vh.Value)); //utiliza as trackbars HSV para ver a cor pretendida 

//Dilatacao seguida de erosao para fechar o ruido
CvInvoke.cvDilate(frame_drone_processado, frame_drone_processado, elemento_dilatacao, 1);
CvInvoke.cvErode(frame_drone_processado, frame_drone_processado, elemento_erosao, 1);

frame_drone_processado.SmoothGaussian(9); //Filtro gaussiano na imagem binaria        

frame_drone_canny = frame_drone_processado.Canny(new Gray(50), new Gray (150)); //Canny

//Show Pictureboxes
picturebox_canny.Image = frame_drone_canny.Bitmap; // Mostra imagem canny
picturebox_hsv.Image = frame_drone_hsv.Bitmap; //mostra imagem hsv
processadamaster.Image = frame_drone_processado.Bitmap; //Mostra a imagem processada
originalmaster.Image = frame_drone.Bitmap; // Mostra a imagem original
```

What is happening? Any idea? :/

**Edit: I know hue range is from 0-255. I was just testing if it wasnt 0-360 when i took the photo**

**Edit 2: I tried to use CvtColor function and the program closes.**

```
 CvInvoke.cvCvtColor(frame_drone, frame_drone_hsv, COLOR_CONVERSION.CV_BGR2HSV);
```

Error: 
`Exception thrown: 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' in Emgu.CV.dll`

But if I do

> CvInvoke.cvCvtColor(frame_drone, frame_drone, COLOR_CONVERSION.CV_BGR2HSV);

It works perfectly but I have HSV image on my original image and I can't use:

```
frame_drone_processado = frame_drone_hsv.InRange(new Hsv(hl.Value, sl.Value, vl.Value), new Hsv(hh.Value, sh.Value, vh.Value)); //utiliza as trackbars HSV para ver a cor pretendida
```

Because it says:

```
Cannot Convert Bgr to Hsv
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's stupid but might help someone. It works like this:

```
// Convert image from RGB to HSV
frame_drone_hsv = frame_drone.Convert<Hsv, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp(); 
CvInvoke.cvCvtColor(frame_drone_hsv, frame_drone_hsv, COLOR_CONVERSION.CV_BGR2HSV);
```

But still a lot of noise. Is there a better approach than mine?

[image]

Comment: You should use YUV color space instead.

Comment: Is there a good reason to do it? Everyone says to use HSV. The problem is that i need to detect multiple colors in the squares (like red,blue,green,yellow) so I need to leave Hue at 0-255.

Comment: There is no Yuv image type. There is only Ycc

Image<Yuv, Byte> frame_drone_yuv = new Image<Yuv, Byte>(1280, 720);

Comment: The thing is that HSV is a pseudo-color space rather outdated and not respectful of what really is a color, esp. saturation.